# SqlAlchemy Join on Graph Structure

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am creating a graph structure using the ORM below and am able to do inserts.

Base = declarative_base()

```
class Link(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'base_link'
    _constraints = ['first_id', 'second_id']
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(*_constraints, name = 'link_constraint'), {"schema":"my_schema"})
    id = Column(CHAR(32), primary_key=True)
    object_type = Column(String(16))
    first_id = Column(CHAR(32), ForeignKey(Node.id))
    second_id = Column(CHAR(32), ForeignKey(Node.id))
    orl1 =relationship('Node', foreign_keys=first_id)
    orl2 =relationship('Node', foreign_keys=second_id)

class Node(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'node'
    _constraints = ['h_name', 'd_name']
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(*_constraints, name='node_constraint'), {"schema":"my_schema"})
    h_name = Column(String(256),nullable=False)
    d_name = Column(String(256),nullable=True)
    id = Column(CHAR(32),primary_key=True)
```

I am having a hard time querying the above Objects
for example:

[Case-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbozN.png)

[Case-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cUHe.png)

Case-1 
my join was pretty much straightforward for Case-1(ref case-1.png).

```
  Usage = aliased(Link, name = "Usage")
  node_1 = aliased(Node, name = "node_1")
  node_2 = aliased(Node, name = "node_2")
```

The query will be

```
session.query(node_1, node_2).join(Usage, node_1.id == Usage.first_id).join(node_2, node_2.id == Usage.second_id)
```

How would my join be for my Case-2 (ref case-2.png)?

```
  Usage = aliased(Link, name = "Usage")
  Usage_2 = aliased(Link, name = "Usage_2")
  node_1 = aliased(Node, name = "node_1")
  node_2 = aliased(Node, name = "node_2")
  node_3 = aliased(Node, name = "node_3")
```

I cannot quite properly build the query

the query below is as close as I can get

```
session.query(node_1, node_2, node_3).join(Usage, node_1.id==Usage.first_id).join(Usage_2, node_3.id==Usage_2.first_id).join(node_2, and_(node_2.id==Usage.second_id,  node_2.id==Usage_2.second_id))
```

which I know is wrong. It will be really nice if someone could point me in the right direction for my case-2 join.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question in sqlalchemy group and got a bit of insight into how to solve my problem, chk the link below.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/L9u3LuJp-AY